# Handle POST from android client

Tags: java, android, playframework-2.0, httpclient

I'm using Play! framework(2.0.4) as rest servise from my android app. I want to send POST request from android but receive the error message from routes.
This is how my route file looks like

```
POST     /addText/:txt                               controllers.Application.addText(txt: String)
```

and POST request from android

```
int response = HttpRequest.post("localhost:9000/addtext/").send("txt=some text").code();
```

im using Http Request [library](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
POST     /addText                               controllers.Application.addText
```

and in the controller:

```
public static Result addText() {
    String txt = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("txt")[0];
    return ok(...);
}
```

See: http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/play-framework-posted-values-revisited/

or `DynamicForm`

```
public static Result addText() {
    DynamicForm df = form.bindFromRequest();
    String txt = df.get("txt");
    return ok(...);
}
```

Finally you can also declare some model, and then bind it whole from request (which is best option when you are gonna to validate incoming data and later save it to DB): [Play doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaForms)